# Editor Pane in IWpfTextView is not Editable

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I am trying to create a Visual Studio extension that will open a document window containing a custom control of mine that hosts an editor pane.  I can get the document to load, the correct content type loads with my custom content extensions (classifier, quick info), a window with my custom control showing the editor pane loads, but the text cannot be modified.  I can select and highlight text, but no keys work, no commands, and no mouse input other than text selection.

The following is what I have in my Package class:

```
[PackageRegistration(UseManagedResourcesOnly = true, AllowsBackgroundLoading = true)]
[ProvideEditorExtension(typeof(MyCustomEditorFactory), ".cust")]
[Guid(MyCustomExtensionsPackage.PackageGuidString)]
public sealed class MyCustomExtensionsPackage : AsyncPackage
{
    public const string PackageGuidString = "ec2c4646-d0cc-42c6-b0a6-d0ff3e318cef";

    #region Package Members

    protected override async Task InitializeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, IProgress<ServiceProgressData> progress)
    {
        await this.JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync(cancellationToken);
            
        RegisterEditorFactory(new MyCustomEditorFactory(this));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

I have verified that the RegisterEditorFactory method is called, and that my editor factory is called when files with the .cust extension are opened.

The following is my editor factory:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid(EditorFactoryGuidString)]
public sealed class MyCustomEditorFactory : IVsEditorFactory
{
    public const string EditorFactoryGuidString = "38AD95BA-8891-46A2-A5EA-25F5F36EEAE0";
    private MyCustomExtensionsPackage _package;
    private Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider _vsServiceProvider;

    [Import]
    public IContentTypeRegistryService ContentTypeRegistry { get; set; }

    [Import]
    public ITextEditorFactoryService TextEditorFactory { get; set; }

    public MyCustomEditorFactory(MyCustomExtensionsPackage package)
    {
        _package = package;
    }

    public int SetSite(Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider psp)
    {
        _vsServiceProvider = psp;
        return (VSConstants.S_OK);
    }

    public int Close()
    {
        return (VSConstants.S_OK);
    }

    public int MapLogicalView(ref Guid rguidLogicalView, out string pbstrPhysicalView)
    {
        pbstrPhysicalView = null;
        return (VSConstants.LOGVIEWID_Primary == rguidLogicalView ? VSConstants.S_OK : VSConstants.E_NOTIMPL);
    }

    public int CreateEditorInstance(uint grfCreateDoc, string pszMkDocument, string pszPhysicalView, IVsHierarchy pvHier, uint itemid, IntPtr punkDocDataExisting, out IntPtr ppunkDocView, out IntPtr ppunkDocData, out string pbstrEditorCaption, out Guid pguidCmdUI, out int pgrfCDW)
    {
        ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();

        ppunkDocView = IntPtr.Zero;
        ppunkDocData = IntPtr.Zero;
        pbstrEditorCaption = string.Empty;
        pguidCmdUI = VSConstants.GUID_TextEditorFactory;
        pgrfCDW = 0;
        int retVal = VSConstants.E_FAIL;

        if ((grfCreateDoc & (VSConstants.CEF_OPENFILE | VSConstants.CEF_SILENT)) != 0)
        {
            IVsTextLines textBuffer = null;

            if (punkDocDataExisting == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                IComponentModel mef = _package.GetService<SComponentModel, IComponentModel>();
                mef.DefaultCompositionService.SatisfyImportsOnce(this);
                IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService eafs = mef.GetService<IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService>();

                textBuffer = eafs.CreateVsTextBufferAdapter(_vsServiceProvider, ContentTypeRegistry.GetContentType("CUST")) as IVsTextLines;
                string fileText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(pszMkDocument);
                textBuffer.InitializeContent(fileText, fileText.Length);

                string[] roles = new string[]
                {
                    PredefinedTextViewRoles.Analyzable,
                    PredefinedTextViewRoles.Editable,
                    PredefinedTextViewRoles.Interactive,
                    PredefinedTextViewRoles.Document,
                    PredefinedTextViewRoles.PrimaryDocument
                };
                IWpfTextView dataView = TextEditorFactory.CreateTextView(eafs.GetDataBuffer(textBuffer), TextEditorFactory.CreateTextViewRoleSet(roles));
                dataView.Options.SetOptionValue(DefaultTextViewHostOptions.LineNumberMarginName, true);
                dataView.Options.SetOptionValue(DefaultTextViewHostOptions.ShowCaretPositionOptionName, true);
                dataView.Options.SetOptionValue(DefaultTextViewHostOptions.ChangeTrackingName, true);
                dataView.Options.SetOptionValue(DefaultTextViewOptions.ViewProhibitUserInputName, false);

                IWpfTextViewHost wpfHost = TextEditorFactory.CreateTextViewHost(dataView, false);
                MyCustomEditor editor = new MyCustomEditor(wpfHost);

                ppunkDocData = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(textBuffer);
                ppunkDocView = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(editor);

                retVal = VSConstants.S_OK;
            }
            else
            {
                    
                    //code for document already open
            }
            else
            {
                retVal = VSConstants.E_INVALIDARG;
            }
        }
        return (retVal);
    }
}
```

There's a lot to unpack there, but ultimately I'm just

1. Creating an [IVsTextBuffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.textmanager.interop.ivstextbuffer?view=visualstudiosdk-2022) from an [IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.editor.ivseditoradaptersfactoryservice?view=visualstudiosdk-2022)
2. Loading the contents of the text buffer
3. Creating an [IWpfTextView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.iwpftextview?view=visualstudiosdk-2022) with the IVsTextBuffer from a [ITextEditorFactoryService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.itexteditorfactoryservice?view=visualstudiosdk-2022)
4. Creating an [IWpfTextViewHost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.iwpftextviewhost?view=visualstudiosdk-2022) with the [IWpfTextView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.iwpftextview?view=visualstudiosdk-2022) from the same [ITextEditorFactoryService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.itexteditorfactoryservice?view=visualstudiosdk-2022)
5. Creating my my custom [window pane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.windowpane?view=visualstudiosdk-2022) and passing in the [IWpfTextViewHost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.iwpftextviewhost?view=visualstudiosdk-2022)
6. Returning the [IVsTextBuffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.textmanager.interop.ivstextbuffer?view=visualstudiosdk-2022) as the document data and my custom window pane as the document view

My custom window pane code is simply:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[ComVisible(true)]
public sealed class MyCustomEditor : WindowPane
{
    private IWpfTextViewHost _wpfHost;

    public MyCustomEditor(IWpfTextViewHost wpfHost)
    {
        _wpfHost = wpfHost;
        Content = new MyCustomEditorControl(wpfHost.HostControl);
    }
}
```

I've omitted the code for the MyCustomEditorControl for the sake of brevity, but just assume it's a simple WPF UserControl with a ContentPresenter.  The constructor just sets Content property of the ContentPresenter with the wpfHost.HostControl that's passed in.

All of this works insofar as displaying the contents of a file, but I just can't edit anything.  It's like the input bindings aren't wired up or enabled, but I can't find what properties to set or enable on which objects, and the documentation is rather poor on this topic.  I've gone through the Visual Studio extensions walkthroughs on MSDN, but it seems to be a mish-mash of pre-WPF and post-WPF APIs with no clear guidance on what the authoritative approach is.

Admittedly, I may be naive in assuming that the IWpfTextView would automatically handle user input, but in my defense it's created from an [ITextEditorFactoryService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.itexteditorfactoryservice?view=visualstudiosdk-2022) and having "TextEditor" in the name carries certain implications.

I'm going to go through a rather exhaustive list of things I've tried and checked to hopefully help narrow down the possibilities or where my mistake is:

- After the document window is open, I've checked the Running Document Table and there is an entry for it that is automatically created after CreateEditorInstance exits.  It links to the data buffer that's returned, the correct file path, and has an edit lock but no read lock.  I've inspected the RDT when C# files are opened in a normal editor window and those have read and write locks.  I tried manually setting a read lock on the RDT as well, the counter increments, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.
- I've inspected the return result from [ITextBuffer.CheckEditAccess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.itextbuffer.checkeditaccess?view=visualstudiosdk-2022) on the data buffer and it returns **true** so the text buffer is reporting it's editable.
- The textview roles DO have an effect on the final rendered IWpfTextViewHost.  If I add or omit roles, the appearance and functionality changes.  For example, adding or removing "ZOOMABLE" adds or removes the dropdown box with the control zoom level.  However, "EDITABLE" has no effect on editability.
- The editor options DO have an effect.  For example, adding or removing the line number margin options does show/hide the line numbers.  However, [ViewProhibitUserInputName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.defaulttextviewoptions.viewprohibituserinputid?view=visualstudiosdk-2022) has no effect on editability.
- I don't create a code window with [CreateVsCodeWindowAdapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.editor.ivseditoradaptersfactoryservice.createvscodewindowadapter?view=visualstudiosdk-2022#Microsoft_VisualStudio_Editor_IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService_CreateVsCodeWindowAdapter_Microsoft_VisualStudio_OLE_Interop_IServiceProvider_) because the resulting IWpfTextViewHost that can be retrieved from [GetWpfTextViewHost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.editor.ivseditoradaptersfactoryservice.getwpftextviewhost?view=visualstudiosdk-2022) is already parented to another control.  If I disconnect it with (IWpfTextViewHost.HostControl.Parent as Border).Child = null, then the contents of IWpfTextViewHost.HostControl gets disposed of for some reason.  The IWpfTextViewHost.HostControl loads and it displays a window with margins and scrollbars, but the content is blank and if I click into the left margin of the content pane then Visual Studio throws an ObjectDisposedException.  Please note I'm not nulling out the host control itself or its contents, I'm only telling its existing parent it no longer has a child.
- I've inspected the editor GUID property of the IVsWindowFrame that opens my document and it's set to the value returned in the pguidCmdUI parameter, which I believe is correct.
- I'm not certain if the value being set for the pguidCmdUI parameter in the editor factory [CreateEditorInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivseditorfactory.createeditorinstance?view=visualstudiosdk-2022#Microsoft_VisualStudio_Shell_Interop_IVsEditorFactory_CreateEditorInstance_System_UInt32_System_String_System_String_Microsoft_VisualStudio_Shell_Interop_IVsHierarchy_System_UInt32_System_IntPtr_System_IntPtr__System_IntPtr__System_String__System_Guid__System_Int32__) is correct.  I'm aware it's used for command routing, which might explain why I can't type or use the mouse, but I'm not sure what the correct value should be.  I read somewhere it's supposed to be the GUID of the factory that created the editor, so I set it to the text editor factory GUID since that's what created the IWpfTextView.  I tried setting it to my editor factory GUID at the top of the file, as well as typeof(IWpfTextView).GUID, Guid.Empty, and assorted other GUIDs, but there's no change.
- If I pass my IWpfTextView into [IVsEditorAdapterFactoryService.GetViewAdapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.editor.ivseditoradaptersfactoryservice.getviewadapter?view=visualstudiosdk-2022#Microsoft_VisualStudio_Editor_IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService_GetViewAdapter_Microsoft_VisualStudio_Text_Editor_ITextView_), I get back null.
- If I create a IVsTextView from [IVsEditorAdapterFactoryService.CreateVsTextViewAdapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.editor.ivseditoradaptersfactoryservice.createvstextviewadapter?view=visualstudiosdk-2022#Microsoft_VisualStudio_Editor_IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService_CreateVsTextViewAdapter_Microsoft_VisualStudio_OLE_Interop_IServiceProvider_), I can have both an IVsTextView and an IWpfTextView, but the two don't know about each other and I don't know see any way to map them.  I don't even know if they need to be mapped, or if IVsTextView needs to exist or is just the legacy text view interface.
- When I inspect the created IVsTextView, it's base type is a SimpleTextViewWindow that is an undocumented class that's internal to Microsoft's Visual Studio implementation, it has WpfTextView and WpfTextViewHost properties, but they're both null (or throw an exception that they can't be read) and are unsettable.  Microsoft obviously has some internal voodoo magic to map IVsTextViews to WpfTextViews in their own code, but I don't know what it is.
- I'm aware of other code samples that create an IVsInvisibleEditor and get the data buffer from that, but that seems kind of hacky.  I mean, it technically works and no one seems to know of any alternative because the documentation in this area is so poor, so I'm not judging or criticizing, it just seems like that shouldn't be necessary.  It's my (possibly incorrect) understanding that an invisible editor is a virtual editor that is created for documents that are opened in memory but not hosted in a window, but I'm hosting mine in a window.  Additionally all of the working code samples I could find are all copy/pasting from the same Microsoft VSIX code example.  In that example, the virtual editor is created in a tool window that's created under the assumption that a document is **already** open in an existing editor window.  So that tool window is creating a virtual editor side-by-side to a physical one for a tool window.  If I follow the same invisible editor approach, then I'm effectively creating a virtual editor in memory and then a second physical document editor window.  So basically, I'm creating two editors for one document.  That doesn't seem right.  Again, it technically works, but it seems off.
- If the expectation is that we have to implement IOleCommandTarget on our editor window and manually handle every single keystroke, shortcut, and mouse button and manipulate the underlying text buffer directly, then that is going to be the most depressing thing ever.  That would mean they tout being able to use WPF, but then give us a document view without a WPF control that natively handles text editing even though they exist in the framework.

Sorry for the ridiculously long post, but I wanted to provide as much information as I possibly could about where I'm at and what I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding CreateVsCodeWindowAdapter, see the "official" explanation how to make it work: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/projectionbuffertutorial-gives-error-in-dev16/498617